# Sliding Window algorithm in python 3.x. Extracting the before and after values of an element from a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 lists; terms and key_terms. I need to extract the before and after elements from the terms list using the elements from the key_terms list. I have tried the below and it works but it has a bug.

```
terms=['b','a','f','s','w','c','g']

key_terms=['a','w','g']

context_terms=[]

for kt in key_terms:
  if(kt!=0):
    before=terms[(terms.index(kt))-1]

  if(terms.index(kt)==len(terms)-1):
      context_terms.append(before)
      break
  else:
    after=terms[(terms.index(kt))+1]

  context_terms.append(before)
  context_terms.append(after)

print(context_terms)

Output: ['b', 'f', 's', 'c', 'c']
```

The problem with the above is that if the key_terms appear twice in the terms list, the second instance is ignored.

```
terms=['b','a','f','s','a','c','g']

key_terms=['a','g']

context_terms=[]

for kt in key_terms:
  if(kt!=0):
    before=terms[(terms.index(kt))-1]

  if(terms.index(kt)==len(terms)-1):
      context_terms.append(before)
      break
  else:
    after=terms[(terms.index(kt))+1]

  context_terms.append(before)
  context_terms.append(after)

print(context_terms)
Output: ['b', 'f', 'c']
```

The correct output should be `['b', 'f', 's', 'c', 'c']`

After some research i noticed that i have to use a sliding window. Can someone please help me because i can't understand how i am to apply the sliding window for my case. Thank you (P.s this is my first ever question, sorry if my issue is not clear)

Comment: Can you explain what the expected output should be? Also, what do you mean by "if the key_terms appear twice in the terms list, the second instance is ignored"?

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully its more clear now. Does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your problem correctly may be following can help:

```
terms=['b','a','f','s','a','c','g']
key_terms=['a','g']

context_terms=[]

for k in key_terms:
    indices = [i for i, item in enumerate(terms) if item == k]
    for kt in indices:
        before=terms[kt - 1]
        if kt == len(terms)-1:
            context_terms.append(before)
            break
        else:
            after=terms[kt + 1]

        context_terms.append(before)
        context_terms.append(after)

print(context_terms)
```

Output: `['b', 'f', 's', 'c', 'c']`

Answer (score 1):

Try looping over `terms` instead of `key_terms`. For every element in `terms` which is present in `key_terms`, add the element prior to and next to it.

The pseudo-code would be:

```
for e in terms:
    if e present in key_terms:
        ans.add(element_to_left_of_e)
        ans.add(element_to_right_of_e)
```

As opposed to finding indices later, the following pseudo code might prove better to iterate over indices:

```
for index in range(0, length of terms):
    if terms[index] present in key_terms:
        ans.add(terms[index-1])
        ans.add(terms[index+1])
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that when appending element_to_left_of_e of the second occurrence of 'a' in my case, the program will think that you are referring to the first occurrence. Am I missing something or? to clarify, this is the output= ['b', 'f', 'b', 'f', 'c']

Comment: Sorry @guzi I could not understand the comment. Why should there be any difference when either the first or second occurrence of a character is encountered?

Comment: because i need the left and right element of both occurrences of the letter 'a'. Whats happening now is that when i specify that i need the index of 'a', it will always point to the first occurrence in the terms list and not the second.

Comment: Ohh! So rather than iterating over tbe character, iterate over the indices in terms. Then search if the character at the given index exists in key_terms. If so, add characters at previous and next indices.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/dinawidome.cs this is based on the first pseudo code you posted. I will now attempt the second one.